# Better Person vs Better Persons

Tags: grammar

Is it grammatically correct to say...

> He makes others want to be **a better person**.

If so, what about...

> He makes others want to **be better persons**.

This sounds a bit off to me, but it seems grammatically correct. If I use '*better people*' instead, it's sounding much off by becoming somewhat distant/impersonal, so I'm not considering that.

If both ways are correct, what's the difference?

Comment: Grammar is a low bar to cross. Both are grammatical.

Comment: _People_ does not sound distant or impersonal - it's the word we normally use when referring to human beings in the plural. _Persons_ is only used in certain formal contexts, for instance a notice stating how many may safely travel in a lift (elevator).

Comment: I would steer clear of *persons*.

Comment: In fact, I would steer clear of *person* as well. Is there anything wrong with: *He makes others want to be better.*

Comment: @JimSimson But wouldn't 'persons' add specificity, though? Without it, wouldn't it be hard to guess unless the context obviously means it?

Comment: @VKBoy, that's a fair question, but no. First, if I say that you make others want to be better, "others" can only really mean other people. You wouldn't be making other squirrels want to be better. Second, by not specifying how the others would be better, the phrase conveys a betterment overall --A better person.

Comment: _He makes people want to be better._ Why use _persons_, and why repeat it? Who else are you talking about?

Comment: @JimSimson (Also to John Lawler) Without the word 'persons,' the sentence can mean many things, f the context isn't so obvious, right? A better father, better thief, better writer, etc. In such cases wouldn't 'persons' or 'person' be necessary?

Comment: VKBoy, I think I've answered that, as has @John Lawler.

Comment: @JimSimson No. You've talked of the possibility of others being none other than humans. I, on the other hand, commented on being specific about what others could be better at.

Comment: I think you should read my comment again. Start with, "Second..."

Comment: @JimSimson But your betterment doesn't specify the field it requires betterment in. My issue was never about who 'others' were, or with just getting better at some random thing. It was about specificity, and your suggestion isn't including that. Hope you understand now.

Comment: Good luck with your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that grammatically it is better to say

> He makes others want to be better *persons* (although ***people*** would be more common).

***Others*** and ***persons*** are connected to each other and should be both in the plural: *The others will be better persons/people*

However, the established idiom is [***to be a better person***](https://www.powerthesaurus.org/be_a_better_person/synonyms) and the link gives other possible versions of it. I think you can avoid your problem by saying:

> He makes one want to be a better person.

Comment: If 'makes others want to be a better person' is wrong, then what about 'makes others want to be better as a person,' or should we be using 'persons' in this statement, too?

Comment: Very good question. Here the singular would be perfectly fine. Although _better as persons_ is not grammatically incorrect, [Google ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=better+as+a+person%2C+better+as+persons&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbetter%20as%20a%20person%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbetter%20as%20persons%3B%2Cc0) will show you that "as a better person" is used much more widely.